# How to make a closing alert in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I would like to make a closing alert by using Bootstrap. The alert was showing correctly, but I could not close it. Is there something wrong in this code? Thanks.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
   <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
   <strong>Warning!</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working proper. Can you added link of `jquery` and `bootstrap.js` in your code?  check this : https://jsfiddle.net/ykts4fpu/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have added `jquery` and `bootstrapjs` files in your project

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class=container>
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    <strong>Warning!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to add links of jquery. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JQUERY

REMOVE

```
$('#alert-container').children('.alert:first-child').remove();
```

APPEND

```
$('#alert-container').append('<div class="alert alert-block fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><h4>Info!</h4>'+ message +'</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class=container>
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    <strong>Warning!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class=container>
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    <strong>Warning!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding further explanations as to why your approach is best. Code only answers are not always helpful to learners.